# Asynchronous task is not reactive in vuejs view

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Default the loading image is true after complete the upload loading image is false, but after update the loading object no effect in view, always show the loading bar.

Where is my mistake, please help anyone,

Note: also try by this.$nextTick() function, same output;

in console the update we got, but no effect in view

```js
Vue.config.devtools=false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data: {
    isloadingImage: [],
    property:{
      images:[]
    }
  },
  methods: {

    addFiles() {
      this.$refs.files.click();
    },

    handleFilesUpload() {
      let uploadedFiles = this.$refs.files.files;
      let maxLength = uploadedFiles.length <= 4 ? uploadedFiles.length : 4;
      for (let i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
        uploadedFiles[i].url = URL.createObjectURL(uploadedFiles[i]);
        this.property.images.push(uploadedFiles[i]);
      }
      this.uploadImages();
    },

    removeFile(key) {
      this.property.images.splice(key, 1);
      delete this.isloadingImage[key];
    },
    async uploadImages(){
      this.property.images.forEach((value, key) => {
        if (!this.isloadingImage[key]) {
          this.isloadingImage[key] = true;
          let myFormData = new FormData();
          myFormData.append('title', value);
          axios.post('http://localhost:800/uploadimage',
                     myFormData).then(response => {
            this.isloadingImage[key] = false;
           
          }).catch(error=> {
            
            this.isloadingImage[key] = false;
            console.log(this.isloadingImage);
          })
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.small-image {
        max-height: 200px;
        max-width: 200px;
    }

    .post-image button {
        padding: 0 5px;
    }

    .post-image-preview {
        max-height: 105px;
    }

    .post-image .caption {
        max-width: 198px;
        height: 27px;
    }

    .lds-facebook {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        width: 64px;
        height: 50px;
    }

    .lds-facebook div {
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 6px;
        width: 10px;
        background: #bfbebe;
        animation: lds-facebook 1.2s cubic-bezier(0, 0.5, 0.5, 1) infinite;
    }

    .lds-facebook div:nth-child(1) {
        left: 6px;
        animation-delay: -0.24s;
    }

    .lds-facebook div:nth-child(2) {
        left: 26px;
        animation-delay: -0.12s;
    }

    .lds-facebook div:nth-child(3) {
        left: 45px;
        animation-delay: 0s;
    }

    @keyframes lds-facebook {
        0% {
            top: 6px;
            height: 51px;
        }
        50%, 100% {
            top: 19px;
            height: 26px;
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <div class="field-title"><h5>Pictures</h5></div>

    <div class="form-group post-image">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
                <button class="add-photo" v-on:click="addFiles()"><i
                        class="fas fa-camera"></i></button>
                <input type="file" multiple id="file" ref="files"
                       v-on:change="handleFilesUpload()">
            </div>
            <div class="brows-image-text"><p>You can upload up to<br>4 pictures per
                listing</p></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div v-for="(file, key) in property.images" class="col-md-3">
                <div class="lds-facebook" v-if="isloadingImage[key]">
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                </div>
                <div v-else>
                    <button v-on:click="removeFile( key )" type="button">
                        <i class="fas fa-times text-danger"></i>
                    </button>
                    <img :src="file.url" class="small-image post-image-preview">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See rule #2 here https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/#Why-isn%E2%80%99t-the-DOM-updating

You update `isloadingImage` array's values using its keys. In such a case for the change to be reactive, you need to replace your whole array after the fact.

Example:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:800/uploadimage', myFormData)
  .then(response => {
    this.isloadingImage[key] = false;
    this.isloadingImage = this.isloadingImage.slice(0);
    // ^^^ this line
  }).catch(error=> {
    console.log('error', key, error)
    this.isloadingImage[key] = false;
    this.isloadingImage = this.isloadingImage.slice(0);
    // ^^^ and  line
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use data as function, not as object like you do.

```
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data () {
    return {
      imageIsLoading: ...
```

Comment: do you mean the computed property

Comment: Edited the answer. To make property reactive you shoud define data property of your component as a function.

Comment: i think this is same thing, data function use in single component, same output

Comment: @MakarovSergey, `data` is supplied as a function in components, not in the main view instance.